# Trying to start with google translate API and using ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
<script language="javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">

 $(document).ready(function() { 

 } );
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form onsubmit="return false">

 <input type="button" value="Translate" onclick="gtrans(this.form)" />
 <p id="translation" style="border:1px solid #00f;padding:5px;width:400px">-</p>
</form>
</body>
```

When I add inside `ready(){}` the line `google.load ("language", "1");` the form is not showed, why?

Regards

Javi

Comment: put it outside ready() function

Answer (score 0):

The $(document).ready() function is executed **before** the window loads, as soon as the DOM is registered by the browser. So, as Dalen suggests, you should put your code outside the function.